# Passando variavel JS para ManagedBean

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

Possuo uma variavel em js, e preciso envia-la para meu ManagedBean, qual a forma mais correta de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode manipuar o DOM pra fazer o que precisa, segue um exemplo:

```html
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:inputHidden id="x" value="#{bean.x}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="y" value="#{bean.y}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" onclick="getVars()" action="#{bean.method}" />
</h:form>
```

Sua função Javascript:

```
   function getVars() {
       // ...
       var x = 10; 
       var y = 20;

       document.getElementById("formId:x").value = x;
       document.getElementById("formId:y").value = y;
    }
```

No seu bean:

```
private int x; 
private int y; 
public void method() {
    System.out.println("x: " + x); 
    System.out.println("y: " + y); 
// ... 
}
```

Comment: Tentei desta forma.

<h:inputHidden id="idBancoPai"
     value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.idBancoPai}" />

Porem quando tento receber ele no bean , o valor vem como 0. Não pegando o valor real selecionado. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Sem ver seus códigos, não saberia te responder. Mas tente ver se o  método do bean está sendo invocado antes de passar pelo javascript. Eu já fiz isso (manipular DOM via JS e mandar pro Bean) e não tive problemas.

Comment: Quando voce diz, se o método bean esta sendo invocado antes de passar pelo javascript? seria mais ou menos o que? Porque a principio o que preciso é, clico na linha correspondente, seleciono o id que preciso, ai passo para o input, e pego no bean

Comment: Coloque um breakpoint no seu JS e no Bean, veja se ao clicar no botão (ou qualquer outra coisa) que dispara a action segue a ordem (1º javascript, 2º bean).

Comment: Consegui Marcos, o problema foi bem bobo, eu tinha colocado o <h:inputHidden id="idBancoPai" value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.idBancoPai}" /> em outro form que esta na mesma pagina, com isso toda vez que eu submetia o form para pega-lo no bean o valor zerava. Valeu pela ajuda